# Start windows service before LogonUI appears

Tags: windows, boot, winlogon

I've wrote a service, that should start before WinLogon launches LogonUI, but I can't find any solution to ensure it.

My service belongs to MS_WindowsLocalValidation group, that is located before, for instance, SmartCardGroup, which SCardSvr belongs to. I suppose, LogonUI needs some SCard functionality, so it should wait until this service starts, but it is just a guess. The obvious guess is that WinLogon waits for COM infrastructure launches, but I can't add my service to this group, because it uses COM, so it should start before my service too.

The question is: is there a way to ensure, that my service will start completely (will set its state to `SERVICE_RUNNING`) before LogonUI?

---

I found, that winlogon waits for a named event `Global\\UMSServicesStarted`, but during setup only :( Maybe there is something, that winlogon waits always before starting LogonUI?

Maybe there is some service, that winlogon depends explicitly on...

Comment: Why? If you have code in the logon process, why can't you wait/start your service if you need it?

Comment: For some purposes this service shuold be already in running state when LogonUI appears, because it additionally processes user logon by itself (and hence should be active when user enters their credentials. The only way to ensure it is to start service before LogonUI).

Comment: Appearance of logon UI elements doesn't require any services to be running. Smartcard logon features are displayed as far as corresponding data are read from cards.